# How to draw an arrow edge with ArrowEdgeDrawer in python-graph?

Tags: python, graph, plot, igraph

I want to draw a plot which shows a graph being transformed to another graph using python-graph. So I need an single arrow pointing from the first graph to the second. I'm considering using ArrowEdgeDrawer class, but I cannot find out how to use it properly. Any one can offer me a demo of creating and using an ArrowEdgeDrawer object will be appreciated.

Comment: You got it the wrong way: Asking for example code usually doesn't work out well. You should provide the code that you have. Then we can try to fix or complete it. Please also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrowEdgeDrawer` is not meant to be used to draw arbitrary arrows on a plot; as its name implies, it is an *edge* drawer. Graph drawer classes use `ArrowEdgeDrawer` by default to draw undirected edges as straight lines and directed edges as lines with arrowheads, therefore the public methods of `ArrowEdgeDrawer` take two graph vertices as arguments and not arbitrary points on a plot. In a really convoluted way, you could *probably* create a "fake" graph containing two invisible vertices (with vertex shape = `"none"`) and a directed edge between them, and then overlay this graph on top of your actual graphs, but I think it is much easier to draw on the drawing canvas directly. igraph uses Cairo as the drawing backend, and you can access the Cairo surface of an igraph plot using the `surface` property of an appropriately constructed `Plot` object. You can then create a Cairo drawing context for the surface and draw on it directly. For example:

```
from igraph import Graph, Plot
from cairo import Context

# Create two graphs
g = Graph.Ring(5)
g2 = Graph.Full(5)

# Create a figure containing the two graphs
fig = Plot("test.pdf", bbox=(800, 360), background="white")
fig.add(g, bbox=(20,20,340,340))
fig.add(g2, bbox=(460,20,780,340))

# Force the figure to be drawn
fig.redraw()

# Create a Cairo drawing context
ctx = Context(fig.surface)

# Draw an arrow
ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
ctx.move_to(360,180)
ctx.line_to(430,180)
ctx.stroke()
ctx.move_to(440,180)
ctx.line_to(430,170)
ctx.line_to(430,190)
ctx.line_to(440,180)
ctx.fill()

# Save the figure
fig.save()
```

Comment: Thanks! I did mean to draw a fake graph containing two vertices. But you are right... Using cairo directly is easier.

Comment: How would you do that for any line and not only a straight/horizontal line?

Comment: Well, you need to figure out the angle between the source and target vertices and then calculate the auxiliary points of the arrowhead, similarly to how it is done in igraph's ArrowEdgeDrawer: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/igraph/drawing/edge.py#L297 .